# Today's Nations Alliances

Tags: warfare, military

> If USA attacks North Korea, who will be their allies? Could you give me a list? Thanks!

Comment: "Their" = USA or PDRK? "Attacks" = with or without a resolution of the UN Security Council?

Comment: The allies of the USA or North Korea? Geopolitical reality will, hopefully, prevent the USA committing such military insanity. You need to give more information about what you want to ask in your question. That will improve your question.

Comment: If you want an answer from worldbuilders, give your question a glimpse of worldbuilding. We are not here to compile lists for whatever homework you might have received.

Comment: Attacks with "boots on the ground", or *just a bunch of missiles*?

Answer (score 1):

*Since you've given no scenario, I will create my own and you take it from there.*

At the start of this year, North Korea wanted to do nuclear tests and the USA was very against this, due to the UN sanctions on North Korea regarding nuclear testing.
The USA wanted to pressure North Korea, and North Korea responded with a threat of force.

At this point, China had 150000 troops near its border with North Korea. Why? They just didn't want any refugees pouring into their country (they say). They most likely would not have aided North Korea since their relation has been fragile at best in recent years. Less trading between the two countries. China, however, does not want that North Korea gets South Korean leadership. Or western leadership, for that matter. It's unclear what China would have done, but you could use this as a way to make it the ally of the USA, with agreements about who gets North Korea.

Russia however has been increasing trade with North Korea, among other things. Russia has condemned the nuclear tests and missile launches of North Korea, but at the same time warned other countries not to intimidate North Korea. Probably because North Korea might lash out, with such an unstable leader. Although this still is not a clear ally of North Korea. Yes, they have lots of trading going on and good relations but Russia too moved troops to the border with North Korea to stop any refugees to pour into Russia by the masses, or is it? Could've been troops that were nearby and ready to mobilize and aid North Korea.

The relations with North Korea and any country are fragile and speculative. I also very much doubt the USA would launch an attack as the UN would never approve it, and even if they did then many countries would most likely sit back and watch it all happen, because nobody wants a war and sure as hell don't want to participate if it happens.

**In the end, it's your choice and your world.** If you want the USA to attack North Korea, which is already unlikely, then you can also easily create the alliances which are also unlikely, but possible, like *Russia* and *North Korea* vs *USA*, *China* and *other western nations*. Or *Russia*, *China* and *North Korea* vs the *USA* and *other western nations*.

Answer (score 1):

If the US President simply decides one fine morning to attack, he might have to go it alone. In a preemptive strike against a clear and present danger, *and if some time is spent building a consensus,* there will be more.

- South Korea and Japan are major US allies in the Far East. They are providing bases for US forces and they might *at least* defend those from North Korean counterstrikes. However, there is a history of the Japanese occupation of Korea, in addition to the general WWII legacy. Japan would be reluctant to invade (North) Korea, South Korea would be reluctant to cooperate with a Japanese involvement.
- The US has a long defense cooperation with Australia and New Zealand. Those two might provide smallish contingents.
- The US has a *special relationship* with the UK and the UK still operates with a global reach. The UK might provide another small but capable contingent.
- The original Korean War, many other nations contributed. This war isn't officially over, there is just an armstice. What happens if that breaks down is up for grabs. Will Turkey come again? Ethiopia?

In addition to the *will* to help out, you have to look at the *capability*. Some nations might send token detachments as a show of solidarity, but with little combat effectiveness. The political effect might still make this worthwhile.

Other nations might relieve US forces from other duties (War on Terror, counter-piracy, etc.) and thus free them for operations in Korea.